# Image tag width and height using bootstrap

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, image, twitter-bootstrap

I have a view called ProductSummary.cshtml and it is loading images from the database.  How come with I specify the height within the img tag it is ignored?  The image dimensions are 235px by 234px

ProductSummary:

```
@model SportsStore.Domain.Entities.Product

<div class="well">

@if (Model.ImageData != null)
{
<div class="pull-left" style="margin-right: 10px">
 <img class="img-thumbnail" height="75"
  src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Product",
   new { Model.ProductID })" />
</div>
}


<h3>
    <strong>@Model.Name</strong>
    <span class="pull-right label label-primary">@Model.Price.ToString("c")</span>
</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart"))
{
    <div class="pull-right">
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ProductID)
        @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add to cart" />
    </div>
}
<span class="lead"> @Model.Description</span>
</div>
```

And when I inspect the element using Google Chrome, I get the following:

```
.img-thumbnail {
display: inline-block;
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
padding: 4px;
line-height: 1.428571429;
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try doing an inline style for the image

```
<img class="img-thumbnail" style="height:75px; width:auto;"
  src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Product",
   new { Model.ProductID })" />
```

Comment: I am not sure if in-line css is a good idea. Is there no other workaround?